# Updated hostname of server but old hostname still appearing appearing in Postfix logs?

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, hostname

Been having some trouble with emails bouncing when being sent to certain addresses from our CentOS 6.4 Media Temple DV server.

I am no expert but after checking the mail logs it appeared that they where bouncing because the recipients server didn't recognise the domain of the sender.

```
said: 550 <toltech@mt-toltech.co.uk>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
```

But I can't get my head around is why mt-toltech.co.uk is appearing in the logs at all, as we changed the hostname and primary domain of the server to toltechdigital.co.uk

The following also makes a few appearances in the logs

```
toltechdigital postfix/smtp[3443]: 370A5E38EE: to=<toltech@mt-toltech.co.uk>,
```

Where is this to field being set, I suppose is what I am trying to figure out.

Doing `postconfig -n` returns:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10240000
mydestination = mail.toltechdigital.co.uk, localhost.toltechdigital.co.uk, localhost, toltechdigital.co.uk
mydomain = toltechdigital.co.uk
myhostname = toltechdigital.co.uk
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 70.32.91.66/32
myorigin = mail.toltechdigital.co.uk
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = 
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/samples
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:110
```

I have limited experience with configuring Postfix so i am assuming my configuration is the problem, however I am still perplexed as to where the mentions of the old hostname are coming from.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not Postfix. Whoever sent the mail used that address.

Comment: The emails are being generated from the Wordpress plugin Ninja Forms, so  what your saying would suggest that the plugin is the culprit yet I can't find any mention of the mt-toltech.co.uk domain in any of the settings for the plugin. Talk about being confused....

Comment: What's the output of `hostname -f`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have set the `myorigin` parameter directly in your config file.  However you might want to check the `/etc/mailname` file to see if any lingering remnants of your old hostname are still there.  Maybe some part of postfix is still using it.

Also, did you rebuild your aliases database using the `newaliases` command?

Comment: Thanks, an incorrect hostname in `/etc/mailname` was the issue for me